# Javascript: How to cast unsigned 64-bit in unsigned 32-bit?

Tags: javascript, casting

I'm trying to do an operation on unsigned 32-bit integer in JavaScript.

```
var res = Uint32Array(1);
res[0] = 100520624621013250
// 100520624621013250
res[0]
// 3139619072
```

But:

- `100520624621013250` is `0x1651ef9bb22c902`
- `3139619072` is `0xbb22c900`

What happens during the cast? Why does the `...2` is lost?

Another example:

```
(100520624621013250).toString(16)
// "1651ef9bb22c900"
```

While conversion websites[1](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter),[2](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/decimal-to-hex.htm),[3](https://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html) gives `0x1651EF9BB22C902` for the same input value.

Comment: What `...2`? Can you explain a bit more? How are you actually converting it, your example doesn't show that.

Comment: I was expecting `0x1651ef9bb22c902` to be casted to `0xbb22c902`, but it is casted to `0xbb22c900`. Hence the `...2`.

Comment: Please may you update your example to be a [mcve]?